# MassTransit : how to retrieve the content of the message in the IRetryObserver

Tags: masstransit

using the IRetryObserver, I'm watching and logging all retry attempts, and their final results (whether the message was finally successfully processed or not).

I wonder if it's possible to access the json payload of the message within the methods of the observer ?

I managed to access the type of the message, using this piece of code :

`context.ContextType.IsGenericType?context.ContextType.GetGenericArguments().First().Name:"Unknown";`

But i can't find a way to get the message content

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do so, the inner context of RetryContext was a class that derives from the ConsumeContext interface, which exposes the message.

I'm not sure this will always be true, but in my case it did the trick :

```
private static bool TryGetMessagePayload<TContext, TMessage>(RetryContext<TContext> context, out TMessage message)
    where TContext : class, PipeContext
    where TMessage : class
{
    message = null;
    if (context.Context is ConsumeContext<TMessage> consumeContext)
        message = consumeContext.Message;

    return message != null;
}
```

in case you don't know statically the type of message you expect (like if you a have a global RetryObserver for multiple subscriptions), you can also cas as `ConsumeContext<object>`, which will always be true (`public interface ConsumeContext<out T>` : T is covariant).

Then, process the message untyped : get its json payload, persist it somewhere, etc